# raw socket listener

Tags: c, linux, sockets, network-programming

This is a quick question for linux c programming raw sockets. If I wanted to just listen to any interface with a raw socket, must I actually bind to an ip address or interface to listen to traffic? From what I understand, I feel like I should be able to just call sock(); and then start recvfrom() traffic. Maybe I'm wrong, but I've seen some programs that don't use it.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You are right, the only thing you will need to do is call `socket()` and then `recvfrom()`. Nevertheless be aware of the fact that there are some limitations with listening using `SOCK_RAW`.

> If you're not using raw sockets on a "send-and-forget" basis, you will
>   be interested in reading the reply packet(s) for your raw packet(s).
>   The decision logic for whether a packet will be delivered to a raw
>   socket can be enumarated as such:
>
> 1. TCP and UDP packets are never delivered to raw sockets, they are always handled by the kernel protocol stack.
> 2. Copies of ICMP packets are delivered to a matching raw socket. For some of the ICMP types (ICMP echo request, ICMP timestamp request,
>      mask request) the kernel, at the same time, may wish to do some
>      processing and generate replies.
> 3. All IGMP packets are delivered to raw sockets: e.g. OSPF packets.
> 4. All other packets destined for protocols that are not processed by a kernel subsystem are delivered to raw sockets.
>
> The fact that you're dealing with a protocol for which reply packets
>   are delivered to your raw socket does not necessarily mean that you'll
>   get the reply packet. For this you may also need to consider:
>
> 1. setting the protocol accordingly while creating your socket via socket(2)system call. For instance, if you're sending an ICMP
>      echo-request packet, and want to receive ICMP echo-reply, you can set
>      the protocol argument (3rd argument) to IPPROTO_ICMP).
> 2. setting the protocol argument in socket(2) to 0, so any protocol number in the received packet header will match.
> 3. defining a local address for your socket (via e.g. bind(2)), so if the destination address matches the socket's local address, it'll be
>      delivered to your application also.

For more details you can read e.g. [this](http://www.enderunix.org/docs/en/rawipspoof/).

Comment: 1 million thank you's!:) I couldn't find any good information about recieving packets on a raw socket, but thanks again for enlightening me. Now I know that I should use bpf if I want to into raw sockets.

Comment: Great answer. The final link is unavailable at the moment (perhaps just temporarily?) but is mirrored at https://web.archive.org/web/20190716060924/http://www.enderunix.org/docs/en/rawipspoof/

Answer (score 1):

If you meant to capture the traffic on a interface, you can use libpcap.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I will probably use libpcap over bpf since it seems much easier to analyze packets. I learned something to day!