# Listen: Operation Not supported error

Tags: c, sockets, listen

I am working on a raw sockets program in `Ubuntu` using `C` programming language. As I am using raw sockets, I need to use the `SOCK_RAW` type instead of `SOCK_STREAM`. Using `SOCK_RAW` in turn disables me from using the `listen()` by throwing a

```
"Listen:Operation not supported error".
```

What do I do to rectify this?
 Below is the code I am working on:

```
<header files>
.
.
if((sock=socket(AF_INET,SOCK_RAW,IPPROTO_RAW))==-1)
{
perror("Socket");
exit(1);
}
if(setsockopt(sock,SOL_SOCKET,SO_BROADCAST,&true,sizeof(true))==-1)
{
perror("Setsockopt");
exit(1);
}
server_addr.sin_family=AF_INET;
server_addr.sin_port=htons(9392);
server_addr.sin_addr.s_addr=INADDR_ANY;
bzero(&(server_addr.sin_zero),8);
if(bind(sock,(struct sockaddr *)&server_addr,sizeof(struct sockaddr))==-1)
{
perror("Unable to bind");
exit(1);
}
if(listen(sock,5)==-1)
{
perror("Listen");
exit(1);
}
printf("\nTCP Server waiting for client on port 9392");
fflush(stdout);
while(1)
{
sin_size=sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);
connected=accept(sock,(struct sockaddr *)&client_addr,&sin_size);
printf("\nI got a connection from (%s,%d)",inet_ntoa(client_addr.sin_addr),ntohs(client_addr.sin_port));
while(1)
{
printf("\nSEND (q or Q to quit):");
scanf("%s",send_data);
if(strcmp(send_data,"q")==0||strcmp(send_data,"Q")==0)
{
send(connected,send_data,strlen(send_data),0);
close(connected);
exit(0);
}
else
send(connected,send_data,strlen(send_data),0);
bytes_recieved=recv(connected,recv_data,1024,0);
recv_data[bytes_recieved]='\0';
.
.
.
.
```

Comment: It doesn't make sense to call `listen` on a raw socket, because raw sockets can't accept connections. What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because "Listen()" is not supported on Raw socket.

please check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13082023/raw-socket-listener)